# Microsoft Office Add in Javascript, How can I have a message to Junk folder

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to make a javascript outlook add-in using this API and generator.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis
https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office

What I want to do is below.

1. Select an Email.
2. Show taskpane of add-in.
3. Click some button on taskpane.
4. the Email move to Junk Folder.

Though I could make an add-in which shows taskpane and specify an Email, I couldn't figure out how can I move the Email to Junk Folder.

What kind of API should I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EWS request to send a mail to junk folder .Please follow these documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/markasjunk-operation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/movefolder-operation .You can use makeEwsRequestAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_) to make EWS calls

Comment: Thanks, then I have a question.  The first xml of your first link has "ItemIds" section,  in 
  this section, I cannot figure out what "changeKey" parameter is. While How to get "ItemId" from email is presented last link. Is there any API to get  "changeKey"?

Comment: Please use findItem (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/finditem-operation?redirectedfrom=MSDN ) for that

Comment: I tried to follow your instruction, but it returns GenericResponseError. Do you have any knowledge?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428362/microsoft-office-add-in-javascript-markasjunk-request-returns-genericresponseer

Comment: As you have created new post for this on Stackoverflow. Let's continue discussion on this there.