# Microsoft Office Add in Javascript, MarkAsJunk Request returns GenericResponseError

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to make a javascript outlook add-in using this API and generator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office

Since I would like to have a specific message to move to junk folder, I tried to follow these process.

I could get information using `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/markasjunk-operation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_

Then, I finally tried to markAsJunk request and it returned  `GenericResponseError`.

The environment to which I installed my add-in is MS365 Outlook web app, and I'm hosting my add-in in office generator localhost dev-server.

here is the code.

`item.itemId` is `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`.

`changeKey` is a ChangeKey got in another part of code.

```
    const request =
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:m="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
                   xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <m:MarkAsJunk IsJunk="true" MoveItem="true">
                <m:ItemIds>
                    <t:ItemId Id="${item.itemId}" ChangeKey="${changeKey}" />
                </m:ItemIds>
            </m:MarkAsJunk>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope> `


    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.error.message)
    })
```

here is the error message

```
{"status":"failed","error":{"name":"GenericResponseError","message":"The request is invalid.","code":9020}}
```

How can I solve this? Is there any part should I fix or some settings should I check ?
Thanks a lot.

[error showed in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5kG6.png)

Comment: Are you able to execute the action successfully outside of Outlook web add-ins?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to I execute the action outside of Outlook web add-ins. I tried to execute same action on Outlook desktop(mac), result was same. it must be able to get information via makeEwsRequestAsync, but the mail never move to junk folder

Comment: To understand whether this is a limitation of OfficeJS (`makeEwsRequestAsync`) or not you need to use EWS on your own. Because OfficeJS provides a limited access to EWS operations, some operations are not available/supported for add-ins.

Comment: Can you please try "xmlns" links in request with "http" instead of "https"?

Comment: try "xmlns" links in request with "http" instead of "https"? 
this solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

To understand whether this is a limitation of OfficeJS (`makeEwsRequestAsync`) or not you need to use EWS on your own. Because `OfficeJS` provides a limited access to EWS operations, some operations are not available/supported for Office web add-ins.

Try using [EWSEditor](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/ews-editor/#connecting-to-mailboxes) to connect to the mailbox and run actions manually.